# preparing cms for iphone app development

Tags: iphone, xcode, json, content-management-system

I have created an iphone app which basically pulls json feeds into my iphone..I have created the JSON file manually and put the jSON file in My FTP Server..as far as updation are concered the client gives me the updation via email or skype which i then update my JSON file that is in the server.what i want to develop is a Backened CMS so that the client is able to handle the maintanenece.i m a noob as far CMS is concerned,which is the best place to start..is wordpress a better..Any advice on how this can be achived would be helpful

Comment: Can you explain the role of cms ... ?

Comment: i want something like dis..i ll be providing my client a front end which contains three text box title,description,image...if the client enters data in the text box..it got to get converted into JSON orXML(any Serialized format) so that i will be able to pull the content into my iphone

Comment: you don't require a cms for that..

Comment: no i just gave u a small example...there is a blog,mapview several others things ..i should be able to customize my cms and give it to the client...

Answer (score 0):

[Appnx](http://codecanyon.net/item/appnx-create-an-iphone-app-using-a-web-cms/243415) has a pretty neat backend.

Comment: will de  provide the php code for the cms development.that will be neat

Answer (score 0):

[iPhone-CMS](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/extension-manuals/lp_iphone/2.1.0/view/toc/0/) uses TYPO3 as the backend and can generate native apps.

Comment: i develop application's both for iphone and android..i need the final serialization format to be in json..if i develop a cms ,the final data got to be JSON so that it  could be later consumed by the respective iphone and android app.which is the best place to start..any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at our [JSON-based StorageRoom CMS](http://storageroomapp.com). We built many mobile apps ourselves and always had the content problem, so one day we created our own CMS.